# show/hide specific var keys of an object

Tags: jquery, json, string, key

I have a string of an object that I want to show the name and once a  different link is clicked it will display only the information that pertains to it. So if I click chunk1 it will only display the address once clicked.I know I need to somehow append an ID tag to each a href, but I cant get that to work. Any ideas how to get it functioning correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var jsonp = '[{"Name":"Chunk1", "address":"99 west blvd"},{"Name":"Chunk2","address":"xavier holway park 2344" }]';
    // var jsonp2 = '[{"address":"123"},{"address":"456"}]';
    var sName = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    //var obj1 = $.parseJSON(jsonp2);
    $.each(obj, function () {
        sName += '<p>';
        sName += '<a href="#">';
        sName += this['Name'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a>';
        sName += this['address'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</p>';
     
        

    });

$('span').html(sName);
$('a').click(function (obj) {
alert("this");

});
  
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: you need to show address when you click on name right?

Comment: yes- only when the name is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the address with a tag such as `span` or `p` which is hidden by default, then create a class for the name link to grab them all and bind a click event where it toggles the visibility of the next span to view the address :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var jsonp = '[{"Name":"Chunk1", "address":"99 west blvd"},{"Name":"Chunk2","address":"xavier holway park 2344" }]';
    // var jsonp2 = '[{"address":"123"},{"address":"456"}]';
    var sName = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    //var obj1 = $.parseJSON(jsonp2);
    $.each(obj, function () {
        sName += '<p>';
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink">';
        sName += this['Name'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style="display:none">';
        sName += this['address'] + "</span><br/>";
        sName += '</p>';
     
        

    });

$('span').html(sName);
   /* $('a').click(function (obj) {
alert("this");

});*/

$(".nameLink").click(function(){

$(this).next().toggle();
});
  
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```